# How to use -data curl in PHP

Tags: php, bash, function, curl

With `curl` from linux bash I can download a webpages passing some variables

```
curl --data "var1=val1&var2=val2&var3=&var4=val4&btnSubmit=btnName" https://<url> -o "<fileToSave>"
```

I need to do the same things but to get the full html code of that page into a php variable.
I'm trying with this:

```
<?php $ch = curl_init();


$post_data = array (
    "var1" => "val1",
    "var2" => "val2",
    "var3" => "",
    "var4" => "val4",
    "btnSubmit" => "btnName"
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

The problem is that from bash I can retrieve the html pages and save it with this code my `$response` value is empty.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use `http_build_query()` over the `$post_data`, otherwise curl will assume to `POST` `multipart/form-data` posting based on the `Array` Data type(that's why it is not working for you).

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
```

`http_build_query()` converts the array into `key1=value1&key2=value2` formated string with automatic `urlencode()`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are connecting to a HTTPs URL. You should enable this `cURL` parameter.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```